# query latest record per user include id

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following fields

ID, date, user

now I want to return the ID of the entry with the latest date per user.

I have a solution where I query for the latest date per user and then get the id based on the date and user.

But I want to get the ID directly in one query because I think its wrong to have a JOIN query identify the ID based on date and user.
Doesn't it defeat the whole concept of the ID? What if I have 2 people editing the same user in the same second?

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Why do you need the IDs? Does the table have more columns? Do there exist rows with same `user` and same `date`?

Comment: One of the advantages of using more advanced databses than MS Access is the ability to use `RANK` and `PARTITION`, which make queries like this trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your IDs sequential and increasing?

If so

```
SELECT User, Max(ID), Max(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY user
```

Otherwise, nothing wrong with the join.

Comment: Note: This only works if dates are only entered in chronological order.

Comment: @RedFilter Yes, hence the first line of the answer.

Comment: Your first line says nothing about dates, only IDs. I.e., ID 2 may have a date earlier than ID 1, in which case your query fails.

Answer (score 1):

try this one, it uses subquery to get the latest date per user.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableNAme a INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT  user, MAX(date) maxDate
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP BY user
    ) b ON a.user = b.user AND
            a.date = b.maxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using this information? It is valid to use @@identity with MS Access.

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2 (test) Values('abc')", dbFailOnError

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select @@identity")
Debug.Print rs(0)
```

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with inserts.

Comment: @RedFilter I do, based on this line "Doesn't it defeat the whole concept of the ID? What if I have 2 people editing the same user in the same second"

Comment: I think the OP is referring to doing one query to get max date, and then another query to get full row based on that, and in the mean time another user edits the row, i.e., a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:

> Doesn't it defeat the whole concept of the ID?

The ID (PK) is to uniquely identify a record. There is no guarantee only one record matches a given user and date (since multiple entries could have the same date for the same user). You may have a unique constraint on user/date to avoid this, but in that case you don't need the ID as user and date are enough to uniquely identify the record. So, re-consider your need for the ID column here.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to get the ID and the date for the latest entry of each user?

That would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT `ID`, `date`, `user`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
GROUP BY `user`
```